# Which word goes with which?

Tags: phrases, hyphenation

In today's financial Times I read: "The clearest sign post the referendum..." and it took me a while to parse this.

Does it say "The clearest [sign post]..." or is it a sign "post the referendum"? Of course the latter, but are there any rules that can help me to read such texts more easily without having to go back multiple times to re-parse util all the words fit a proper sentence?

Comment: You could look up signpost / sign post to see whether the open compound is standard.

Comment: What comes AFTER that? The phrase is too short. The clearest sign post the referendum that blah blah blah would be VERY clear. So what comes after it? You need to post the rest of the damn sentence. Not all readers are created equal.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence). There is no rule that will make sure you never take the wrong path. That's the whole point of garden-path sentences. Otherwise they just wouldn't be a thing.

Comment: Thanks. I now know that the re-parsing is not only due to me being a foreigner.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This sentence is particularly misleading because 'sign post' is way more common and expected than 'post' as a preposition, which is almost a neologism (not in the usual list of prepositions in English).

Comment: I disagree completely. The OP should have posted more of the sentence, by not doing so, a mountain is being made of what is surely a molehill as the FT never does garden-path sentences. Like The Economist they have some of the most highly skilled English (both meanings) editors on the planet.

Comment: Oh, and it's not even a sentence, by the way.

Comment: @Lambie The sentence, if completed, will be a garden-path sentence, assuming that the open compound 'sign post' is acceptable. Garden-path sentences are not ambiguous, but this becomes clear only on reading the whole. 'The horse raced past the barn fell down.' has only one correct reading, but most uninitiated readers would assume 'raced' was an active usage until they read on. / But agreed, OP should have posted at least the whole sentence.

Comment: I am sorry if I didn't post a real sentence, and I am sorry that I didn't look it up, and I am sorry I am only a foreigner, but as a result of the latter, sentences such as these confuse me. To me "sign post" and "signpost" mean the same, given that the English langiage doesn't have clear rules as to when to concatenate words, which Dutch and German have, and which to me makes the language a lot clearer and does not lead to garden-paths.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is no sentence. It is a truncated part of a sentence.

Comment: @Lambie According to [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/britain-airports-heathrow-brexit-idUSU8N19X001?feedType=RSS&feedName=industrialsSector), UK Transport Secretary Chris Grayling's complete [and garden-path] sentence was: "This is a really big decision for this country but it's also the clearest sign post the referendum that this country is very clearly open for business." OP has picked up on the possible misdirection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way this appeared in the press yesterday 10/25/2016:
Transport Secretary Chris Grayling told reporters on Tuesday.

"This is a really big decision for this country but **it's also the clearest sign post the referendum that this country is very clearly open for business**," he said.

So, it is very clear that this means: post the referendum.

I could not find it in the FT but **I suspect 1) It is the same sentence or a part thereof** and 2) **The full sentence in the FT is most likely very clear**.

As this was spoken originally, the speaker's intonation would have made the meaning even clearer....

Comment: Your 'even clearer' means that you accept the original could be misconstrued to some extent.

Comment: Yes, from "the clearest.." is the quote in the FT (p.2, Heathrow). But my mis-parse occurred at the end of the phrase I quoted. Point being that reading the whole sentence three times gave me the correct parse, but I stumbled here. It could also have been written as "_the clearest sign, post the referendum,..._" and would have caused no mis-parse.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Please make sure you post the full sentence when you ask a question. That sentence is never confusing. To Lambie, nice answer.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth I didn't say "even clearer".

Comment: "As this was spoken originally, the speaker's intonation would have made the meaning even clearer...." seems clearly to prove that you did.

Comment: It might have been helpful if Paul had posted the whole sentence, to show what went before or after mattered not.

Isn’t most of the problem caused by punctuation? Specifically, that there should be at least one comma between “sign” and “post” and preferably a parenthetical pair “… , post the referendum, …”

Even the speechwriter would be hard pressed to claim that sentence was meant to be written as reported… and even then, with or without anything to do with the referendum, why would you trust either a writer or a speaker who used “the clearest sign… this country is very clearly…”?